# Retrieve API data with requests

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6

I am trying to retrieve switch data via the Meraki API. Instructions and samples for the API's are here:

```
# https://dashboard.meraki.com/api_docs#return-a-switch-port
```

Sample Request

```
$ curl -L \
-H 'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key: <key>' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X GET 'https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/devices/[serial]/switchPorts/[number]'
```

Sample Response

```
Successful HTTP Status: 200

{
  "number": 1,
  "name": "my port",
  "tags": "dorm-room limited",
  "enabled": true,
  "type": "access",
  "vlan": 10,
  "voiceVlan": 20,
  "poeEnabled": true,
  "isolationEnabled": false,
  "rstpEnabled": true,
  "stpGuard": "disabled",
  "accessPolicyNumber": "asdf1234",
  "linkNegotiation": "Auto negotiate"
}
```

I am using Python's requests instead of curl.  My code is: (NOTE I have altered the serial number and API key just for this post. I use the correct values when I run the code)

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# response = requests.get('https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/devices/[serial]/switchPorts/[number]', headers=headers)
response = requests.get('https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/devices/1111-2222-3333/switchPorts/1', headers=headers)
print(response)


# <Response [200]>
```

I am getting back `<Response [200]>` instead of the JSON data that the API above shows.

My HTTP Status is correct, however.  What am I missing in order to actually get back the JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print(response.content)` instead of `print(response)`.

If you want to save the data in a file, you can use:

```
content=response.content
data=open("name_you_want.json","wb")
data.write(content)
data.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `print (response.text)`
instead of `print(response)`
because its printing response status code instead of body text and i guess you want to print response body

Answer (score 0):

With `.content` & `json.loads` you should be able to parse JSON

```
import requests,json

response = requests.get('https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/devices/1111-2222-3333/switchPorts/1')

json = json.loads(response.content)

print(json.get('name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To access *curl* using python, you can run this:

```py
import requests

headers = {
'accept': 'text/html',
'Cookie': 'token=5e1a8b55b0249136a60423aa02b9120a845fa4122ac98ce4e771aec5d772d7d7a18ac22f18cd47727d00bddc2ebcc5cddf8a402d7a302ddffdeb7c6e15cb2a7005f857112',
}

response = requests.get("http://link-ui3.enter.com/data/1.0/auth/getUserByToken", headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print (r.json)
# You will get your json response
```